# How to change origin in axesIIID?

Tags: pst-solides3d

I'm tying to plot a figure with pst-solides3d package and would like to move axis from origin (0,0,0) to (-2,-2, 0).
I checked the available options for axisIIID (ftp://ftp.cam.ctan.org/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf) and changing the origin is not among them. 
Is it possible to change the origin in some other way?

Comment: Without an example of what you've done we can't hope to help here: please edit one in and request reopening.